# VB.NET set embedded object src to byte array? dynamically set src value

Tags: vb.net, arrays, embedding, djvu

I am trying to dynamically set the src attribute inside of embed tags which is in turn inside object tags:

```
<object width=700 height=700>
<embed src=__bytearraycontents___ type="image/vnd.djvu" width="700" height="700" />
</object>
```

When I obtain the byte array and save the image file to test.djvu on my harddrive and then set the src to this, it works fine. My problem is that I don't want to have to write the image to the hard drive, I want the src to be set to the Byte array straight away. Can anyone advise?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

Set the src attribute to a page that returns .djvu files.  The page can be an .aspx or a [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX).  Pass in your unique identifier in the query string in the url in the src.  On your document serving page, make sure the Response.ContentType is "image/x.djvu".

Example:

```
<embed src="YourPageThatServesUpDocuments.aspx?DocumentID=1" type="image/vnd.djvu" width="700" height="700" />
```

Hypothetical Crude Example of YourPageThatServesUpDocuments.aspx's Page Load:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/x.djvu"
'Where GetByteArrayByDocumentID is the code that gets your byte array.
Response.BinaryWrite(GetByteArrayByDocumentID(Request.QueryString("DocumentID")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did as you described but I get this error when running with internet explorer (through visual studio debug) [see photo below]. It works with Firefox and Chrome through visual studio debug, but not IE (version 10) I know there is nothing wrong with the data in the byte array, as if I write the byte array to my local hard drive as a .djvu, i can open it fine (and it is working with chrome and firefox!)

http://i42.tinypic.com/2v2w6rs.jpg

Any suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: You can try using Response.OutputStream.Write instead of BinaryWrite.

Comment: I tried as above but same results. Response.OutputStream.Write(imagedata, 0, imagedata.Length) but I am getting the same small grey box. Whenever I debug in visual studio with firefox or chrome and check the browser add-ons, it appears to be running the DjVu Plugin Viewer. However when debugging with IE, the plugin viewer add-on is not in the list of browser add-ons. Only when opening in IE from hard drive does it invoke the necessary add-on .dll to view djvu files and works correctly. Could it be that this is the problem and if so, how can I force IE to load the browser add-on @ pageload?

Comment: Maybe try Response.Flush() and/or Response.End() after you output.

Comment: Unfortunately I have both lines after the response.binarywrite but still not working (in IE). Still perfect for chrome/firefox.

Comment: Sorry to respond so late but I have a question regarding this method...in your example, NoAlias, you had the src as "YourPage.aspx?DocumentID=1" however what if I wanted to not make this static? I.E. The query string Document ID would be sent to YourPage.aspx depending on the URL that the user typed in... so it could be DocumentID=2, or 3 etc? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, create the embed tag on the server side and add it to the page via a Literal Control.